# How to automatically link work items to the build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I noticed that work items can be linked to a build.  But I don't see a way to automatically link the work items to the build.

On pull requests, we require pull requests to be associated with a work item.  When the pull request is complete, the work item is updated with a link to the commits.

If I look at a branches commit history in TFS, there is a build column.  I assume that the build column would contain the build that the commit is in, but it is always blank.

We want to be able to look at a build and see what work items are contained in the build.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “Automatic linking of a build with associated work items” feature was released in TFS 2017 Update 2. You could enable this feature by toggling the setting under **Options** in your build definition:

[image]

In this way, each successful build associated with the work item automatically appears in the development section of the work item form.

More information you can refer to the blog below:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/25/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/

Comment: This seems to work.  Although it wasn't what I was expecting.  I was expecting a "Build" link type, not an "Integrated in Build" link type.   Thanks for the help

Comment: How can I specify all(*) branches in this(but in azure devops 2020)? I am getting a predefined drop down list to select branches which forces me to select a single branch only

Comment: @Beingnin Try to enter "*" and press Enter on the keyboard, even though list it empty.